# python complained about NameError: name is not defined

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

we have linux server - `rhel 7.2` with `python 2.7` version , and `pip 21` version

This is the python script that I used in order to run the functions as `get_number_of_cars`

```
import os
import sys
script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
print script_dir
python_files_dir = os.path.join(script_dir, 'python_files')
print python_files_dir
sys.path.append(python_files_dir)
from functions import *


val = get_number_of_cars()
```

While the functions python script - `functions.py` is located under `/opt/cars/python_files`

And the function – `get_number_of_cars` is inside the `functions.py` , as the following

```
def get_number_of_cars(path='/tmp/'):
.
.
.

    return number
```

so when I run the script `/tmp/car_agency.py`

we get

```
python  /tmp/car_agency.py
/opt/cars
/opt/cars/python_files
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/car_agency.py", line 15, in <module>
    ComponentName = get_number_of_cars()
NameError: name 'get_number_of_cars' is not defined
```

But this is very strange because we defined the function - `get_number_of_cars` in  `/opt/cars/python_files/functions.py`

***More than that other machines with the same python script are working correctly***

So I am suspecting that something with python modules or python env isn't good

May I get help about this?

Comment: Could you add the actual content of `functions.py`?

Comment: I cant because some sensitve details but the function is there and as I said the other machine with the same scripts are work fine

Comment: It's not very easy to tell without the actual file. Could you create a simple script and see if you can reproduce the issue then share that?

Comment: in the script functions.py we have many function and when I call to any function we get the same error , so this isnt something that relevant to one function , all function that called from functions.py give the same error

Comment: So how can one tell without seeing the contents of the file?

Comment: I dont think its help because when I call to any function , we get the same error and we have 123 function , so its not logical that all function are bad

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217375/discussion-between-jessica-and-nelsongon).

Comment: You are putting your directory at the *end* of `sys.path`.  Apparently, something earlier in the path has a `functions` module that is being imported, instead.  Inserting it at the beginning might be a better idea.  (You can do `import functions; print(functions.__file__)` to see exactly where the conflict is located.)

Comment: Missing a quote after `/tmp/`

Comment: its typo mistake , its not the problem

Comment: Off-topic, but your script will be much simpler if you install your modules in a known location (try using a virtual environment), rather than trying to adjust your Python path inside the script itself.

Comment: Also, your error message wasn't produced by the code you show. (The line number doesn't match up, and you aren't assigning to a variable named `ComponentName`.) What does `print functions.__name__` output after you import it?

Comment: what I get is like this:     print functions.__name__
NameError: name 'functions' is not defined

Comment: about -    ComponentName = get_number_of_cars() , this is one of the functions that I tested

Comment: does `functions.py` define an `__all__` variable?

Comment: @Philippe python 2.7 `import functions; print functions.__file__`

Comment: functions.py not defined the __all__ variable

Comment: Yes it prints "()" :). Point taken though. Is it not problematic to use `print` as a function when it is a statement in Python2.7. For example, could not confusion arise when doing something like `print("x", "y")`.

Comment: when I set in the script  the - import functions; print functions.__file__  , then the script printed the - /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/functions.pyc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217395/discussion-between-jessica-and-l-grozinger).

Comment: @L.Grozinger thank you so much your note help me now its works

Comment: @L.Grozinger please post an answer so I will vote and accept you answer